# bash broken after changing user's home directory

Tags: linux, unix, redhat

I changed my home directory via /etc/passwd. After I logged in with the user again, the console looks weird.

> bash-4.1$

instead of

> [user@vmname foldername]#

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this in `.bashrc` in your new home directory:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \w]\$ '
```

Comment: You just reminded me! I forgot to move all the . files into the new home directory :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what things you edited in the mentioned files. Probably, you forgot to change the /home/user1 to /home/user2 either in the `passwd` file or on the filesystem. Also there is an entry in passwd which tells the default shell for the user.

Read the `usermod` and `groupmod` manpages, `man bash` will be useful too. Check the startup scripts section, too. And as Read the usermod and groupmod manpages, man bash will be useful too.

Not having a proper `.bashrc` might be another reason behind this. Try adding `PS1='[\u@\h \w]\$ '` in your `.bashrc` as *legoscia* pointed out.